# Selenium Pulse Tunneling Issue

Tags: c#, selenium, network-programming, pulse

I need to use pulse to access a website that is in another intranet. However, based on [this issue](https://community.pulsesecure.net/t5/Pulse-Connect-Secure/Overlapping-local-remote-network-issues-with-Pulse/td-p/429), by doing this, I am not able to access my own intranet/localhost.

I have Selenium running on my own computer and if I am not connected to pulse, it is correctly launching it. However, if I am connected I get an error saying:

```
"Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost"
```

I am not sure if there is a way to use Selenium to access said website because of the tunneling involved. I would like to point out that I need to launch Pulse, before I launch Selenium.

I would like to point out that I am using Selenium in C#.